# How do I use user_regs_struct on ARM processor in ptrace-based debugger

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, arm

I am following the code in Chapter 3 of "Learning Linux Binary Analysis". The code is, "A simple ptrace-based debugger".

I am trying to write this in my Raspberry Pi 3, which has an ARM processor. I know that the error means that I have not included the correct header file, but I cannot find what the correct header file is.

I get this error message:

```
field ‘pt_reg’ has incomplete type struct user_regs_struct pt_reg
```

After doing some research, I found asm/ptrace.h, which includes some macros for the registers struct specific to ARM. Am I on the right track? How in the world can I make this work with an ARM processor?

Here are the headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct handle {
  Elf64_Ehdr *ehdr;
  Elf64_Phdr *phdr;
  Elf64_Shdr *shdr;
  uint8_t *mem;
  char *symname;
  Elf64_Addr symaddr;
  struct user_regs_struct pt_reg;
  char *exec;
} handle_t;
```

Comment: The title of your question should contain your question, not some error message. Right now, your question is really confusing because you did that wrong. Please edit it to put the question in the title and the error message into the body.

Comment: Should this `  struct user_regs_struct pt_reg` be `  struct user_regs_struct *pt_reg`?